# What unusual invalid data inputs that will crash a barcode entry text box on an Android App?

Tags: manual-testing, android, boundary-value-analysis

I am testing an Android App created using Java. I am testing a text box which accepts barcodes with a maximum of 17 characters.

I know to test the normal boundary values, nulls, negative data inputs, and so on. I would like to also try unusual invalid and out of the box data inputs that are more likely to crash the application.

I would really appreciate help in coming up with ideas of ways to break this input box.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify what looks like your intentions. Feel free to revert my edits if you think they aren't correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really can't go wrong with the [Big List of Naughty Strings](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings). The list is set up so that you can manually go through the text file list of strings that have caused issues in other inputs, or you can import it into test automation projects and use it there.

Some other things you might consider: if the text box is supposed to accept barcodes, does it do so by scanning them? If so, try scanning a QR code and see what happens. If you have a Square or other card swipe device, see what the field does if you swipe a card with a magnetic stripe (If you use a credit card, make sure you're not sending it anywhere or you're using test stock).

Hook your device up to a keyboard and lean on the keys or fall on the keys. What happens?

Simulate a pet walking across the device at the wrong time. What does that do?

I'd recommend this strategy:

- Start with the Big List of Naughty Strings; then
- Test sending input by non-standard methods (e.g. swipe, scanned, attached keyboard...)

Those two should be more than enough to find any serious issues the application has with input.

(disclaimer: I am not affiliated with the Big List in any way. I just find it an immensely valuable tool for testing)

Comment: Thank you [Kate Paulk](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/422/kate-paulk). [List of naughty strings](https://github.com/minimaxir/big-list-of-naughty-strings/blob/master/blns.txt)  is a useful link.